# Apache Commons Math Optim: should I use 4.0 or 3.6.1? 4.0 seems dead, but 3.6.1 is deprecated…

Tags: mathematical-optimization, apache-commons-math

I want to use Apache Commons Math for Optimisation, but 3.6.1 contains APIs that have been deprecated in anticipation of 4.0, however, the latter seems to have received little development since 2016.

Any advice on which version to use would be greatly appreciated.

(As an aside, any advice on better open source unconstrained optimisation libraries for java would also be appreciated.)

thanks!

Comment: I'm also interested in an answer to this. I'm reluctant to use a library, that had its latest update more than two years ago. Especially given the fact, that there are open bugs in their [bug tracker](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/MATH/issues/MATH-1462?filter=allopenissues). I searched through their [dev mailing list](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/commons-dev/) and found entries dated January this year. Also, there are commits in their [source repo](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=commons-math.git). But why are there no recent maven 4.0 snapshots?

Comment: @derwiwie Hi derwiwie, I don't really know how this stuff works: would it be terrible etiquette to directly ask the devs who are making those occasional commits to v4.0?

Comment: A bit hard to find but there is a fork [Hipparchus](https://www.hipparchus.org/) that seems to be a bit more active.

Comment: @ManuelRossetti sweet! thanks! (personally, this happens to have recently become relevant for me again, while it wasn't for a few years since asking this question)